# Print string in GDB without address

Tags: debugging, gdb, cpu-registers

I want to print register address that point to string

```
x/s $x0
```

I got

```
$77 =0xaabbccdd "SomeString"
```

Hiw can I print only `SomeString`  without `$77 =0xaabbccdd`

Comment: Try `printf "%s",$x0`

Comment: @ssbssa Thay you. You can put that as comment so I will mark that